# Show emoji with mysql and freemarker in java language

Tags: java, freemarker, emoji

I hava changed mysql's character-set to utf8mb4 for storing emoji bytes(4 bytes per Emoji emoticon), And it looks work well in my php project when i write and read them.

However, when i try to show Emoji emoticons in a java web project using freemarker as presentation layer, I can't convert the emoji data to icons because the outputs confused me, One simple Emoji emoticon have bean rendered as six unknown charaters in the freemarker page.
[image: Here should be one Emoji emoticon charater]

I'm using mysql-connector-java(5.1.16) as the mysql driver, my encoding is utf-8, and the mysql server version is 5.5.

The real question is : How to read 4-bytes Emoji from mysql in java language and show in a web page?

Comment: I have a file to mapping Emoji unicode bytes to the real icons, but I can do nothing if i can't recognize the Emoji bytes in java language.

Comment: You put that data into the FreeMarker data-mode somewhere. Check what's in it before that. Maybe it's already wrong before it gets into FreeMarker.